# Database Script

Tags: mysql

Database contains <60-70 tables, procedures, views etc.

Database A:-

script 1: backup of script taken on 30th July.

Database B:-

script 2: backup of script taken on 31st July.

What can the script be, to find the difference between the two .sql scripts using MySQL syntax?

The platform I am using is:
Windows 8 and MySQL.

Comment: are you looking for a script to compare two .sql files?

Comment: Yes, My first priority is script to find the difference between the two sql scripts..

Answer (score 0):

You have a choice of many tools - possibly including one that I wrote. First, check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/225772/compare-two-mysql-databases) on stackoverflow which has treated this subject in detail.

Note that MySQL has its own tools which may be of more interest to you than the commercial ones?

There's [mysqldbcompare](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-utilities/1.3/en/mysqldbcompare.html) straight from the horse's mouth - it's part of the MySQL utilities collection. Take a look [here](http://drcharlesbell.blogspot.ie/2011/06/comparing-databases-with-mysqldbcompare.html) also. Bell is a well known author in the MySQL ecosphere and also in charge of MySQL replication. Another MySQL tool is dbdiff, again part of the native utilities offered by MySQL. Quite what the difference between them is, I'm not sure. I've always used the method I describe below.

If performing a diff on a **huge** file with all the DDL and DML in it sounds like a pain - you could take a look at mysqldumpsplitter. **Disclaimer** - I wrote this tool and its limitations are well documented on [Github page](https://github.com/Verace/MySQLDumpSplitter). You could use it to split the dump into separate table files and compare them one by one. May suit use cases where a number of your tables are reference tables which rarely change?

You could use this in conjunction with [Percona's toolkit](https://www.percona.com/software/mysql-tools/percona-toolkit) - which is well worth the money! :-) It's Open Source and free to use. I've also found [Scootersoft's Beyond Compare](http://www.scootersoftware.com/) tool to be of great use. It's not free and I have no connection to the company.

**NB** Googling the term "mysqldumpsplitter" will give you links to other tools which you may also find useful.